# Merge data inside group Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a `Crystal Report` setup in my WPF Application. The report is grouping data based on `VENDOR NAME` field as shown in attached image. Now what I want is to show data inside a group only once.

I mean as in first group `TOYOTA HOUSE` the Vendor name is repeating although other column values are different. I want is under this group just show this record once and for other columns ADD/sum their values and show. I know I can do that in SQL query but can I do this in crystal report ?

[image: Image of report]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of showing in the details section add it to the group footer section.

suppress details section 
and add totals in group footer